# Html - 2 html template on a webpage and only one reloads

Tags: jquery, html, css

The title of the question is probably very confusing, but with the diagram below it should be clearer.

[image]

The image shows that I want two different html template in a single webpage, and only the main page changes based on what is selected on the sidebar. How can this be done?

can it be done with just css, html and jquery?

Comment: What does `only one reloads` mean?

Comment: You can use iFrame, js/jQuery `$('#main-page').load('url', function () {afterLoad();})`

Comment: @Woo Jiahao - Your question is a bit too broad. Did you try anything ? Do you have some code that you can share with us ? What exactly is giving you a hard time ?

Comment: @Justinas - will iframe cause the website to slow down? what are the pros and cons?

Comment: @DavidDomain - i wanted a webpage where the main page reloads, and the sidebar remains fixed. normally, the navbar reloads with the webpage when it gets to another url, and that is not i want.
I'm also puzzled as to how can i make the url change to the page name, like whatever.com/pageName when I stays in the same html page and only refreshes the content

Comment: With iFrame you don't have any proper access to iFrame content. iFrame will not slow down your website.

Comment: @Justinas ok will try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather here, you want to dynamically reload you content based on selections in the sidebar. The short answer is: Yes this can totally be done with the technologies you described, for starters you should look into the jQuery AJAX functions:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you want to dive deeper into this, there are also frameworks who take care of the this for you, like Backbone.js: http://backbonejs.org/

In this case you define models etc. for parts of your site that you want to reload. Powerful, but kind of complicated in comparison with the simple jQuery solution.

Bonus Tip: Probably the easiest and fastest solution would be to use jQuery.load() (http://api.jquery.com/load/) you just give that the url you want to load:

```
$( "#main-page" ).load( "content.html" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I dont quite understand how ajax can dynamically reload the content.
Normally i use ajax for GET, POST sort of request only.
Another qn would be, how can i change the url, when i reload the content?
@Florian Rachor

Comment: Normally you would do that with "window.history.pushState()", in case of Backbone I think it can handle that for you.

Regarding AJAX & content: Technically loading a complete HTML page with AJAX is also just a GET type of request, with the return value being the content of the page.